# In SQL Server 2016 what is sys.tables is_external field?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016

In SQL Server 2016 the sys.tables appears to have a new field called is_external.  But what does is_external actually mean and what is it used for?

[MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms187406.aspx) says the following, which is not very helpful:

> Indicates table is an external table.
>   0 = The table is not an external table.
>   1 = The table is an external table.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn935021.aspx

Answer (score 3):

This is my interpretation ..

SQL Server 2016 allows you to configure [POLYBASE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt143171.aspx) - accesses and combines both non-relational and relational data - from SQL Server.

It allows you to run queries on external data in Hadoop or Azure blob storage.

SQL server has a column `is_external` to identify that the table is external. You can find more on external tables using `sys.external_tables` catalogue view.

Answer (score 1):

I know what an external table is in Azure, I'm not sure how it would apply to 2016. In Azure SQL Database, if you want to use a table in another Azure SQL DB, you would have to create a reference to it as an external table. All tables native to the database will be flagged as internal tables.